# How do I create only one object of parent and child

Tags: java

Design a class such that only one instance of the class and any of its sub-classes can be created. To clarify: Assume A is such a class and B is derived from A. B does not have any special code apart from extending A.

```
class A { 
  // code of class A
}
public class B extends A{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new A(); // works fine. 
        new A(); // causes an exception 
        new B(); // works fine as this is the first instance of B 
        new B(); // causes an exception.
    }
}
```

But we need to create the object with the **new** keyword.

I try in static value define in parent but this does not help.

Comment: class A                                                                                                                   
{ 
      // code of class A                                         
    
}                                                              
public class B extends A
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   new A(); // works fine. 
   new A(); // causes an exception 
   new B(); // works fine as this is the first instance of B 
   new B(); // causes an exception.
}
}

Comment: use a private static int counter

Comment: Use static initializer. Same the way Singleton classes work. Or probably you are looking for singleton design pattern itself.

Comment: It would be better if you explained what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: Let suppose some one write A class and we are extending class A . if wrote our custom class and try to create object . but parent should allow one object to create particular class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class A {

    private static Map<Class<? extends A>, A> instances = new HashMap<>();

    public A() {
        synchronized (A.class) {
            if (instances.containsKey(this.getClass())) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            instances.put(getClass(), this);
        }
    }
    // code of class A
}

public class B extends A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A(); // works fine. 
        new A(); // causes an exception 
        new B(); // works fine as this is the first instance of B 
        new B(); // causes an exception.
    }
}
```

When you create an instance of `A` or any subclass of `A`, the constructor of `A` it is called.

The constructor checks if an instance of `A` is present in the `Map` `instances`.

If an instance of the current class exists, an exception is thrown.

If no instance of the current class exists (when no exception is thrown), the current object is saved to `instances`.

The `Map` is `static` so the same `Map` is used across all instances (It obviously would not work if every instance of `A` had its own `Map`).

The `synchronized` block makes sure that the map access is thread safe by locking the `Class` object of `A`. Locking the current `Class` object is not thread safe as the `put` method of `HashMap` is not thread safe when creating new objects.

You can also lock `instances` or use a `Set` of `Class`es as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63898225/10871900) from [oleg.cherednik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3461397/oleg-cherednik).

Comment: Maybe explain the singleton design pattern and put a link to it ?

Comment: I just came up with it by myself but I can explain it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A {

    private static final Set<Class<? extends A>> INSTANCES = new HashSet<>();

    public A() {
        synchronized (INSTANCES) {
            if (INSTANCES.contains(getClass()))
                throw new RuntimeException("duplication: " + getClass().getSimpleName());
            INSTANCES.add(getClass());
        }
    }

    // code of class A
}

class B extends A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A(); // works fine.
        new A(); // causes an exception
        new B(); // works fine as this is the first instance of B
        new B(); // causes an exception.
    }
}
```